# How to solve flickering issue in vertical cards infinite scrolling In NextJS and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want the cards to scroll infinite times, I have three containers each has five cards which move from top to bottom in left and right card, and in middle container moving from bottom to top. The code is working fine but this shows a flickering issue when the counting of cards comes to five or the last card.

> Next js Component

```
const ImageDivClass = "w-28 h-28 bg-dark-200 my-6 rounded-xl text-center"


export default function VerticalScrollImages(props){
    return (
        <>
            <div class="h-full w-32 overflow-hidden relative">
                <div class={`absolute move_top_bottom ${props.className}`}>
                    {Array.from({ length: 2 }, (_, spanIndex) => (
                        <span key={spanIndex}>
                            {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => (
                                <div className={ImageDivClass} key={index}>{index + 1}</div>
                            ))}
                        </span>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

> CSS Code

```
.move_top_bottom {
  animation: marqueeTop 25s linear infinite;
}

.reverse {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes marqueeTop {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }

  100% {
    top: -100%;
  }
}
```

> Using component

```
   <VerticalScrollImages className="" />
   <VerticalScrollImages className="reverse" />
   <VerticalScrollImages className="" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the above issue, we need to make sure we provide proper value for the top. You need to adjust the animation loop dynamically according to the number of cards and the width of each card. `top: -104.5%` works for me based on my card conditions.

```
@keyframes marqueeTop {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }

  100% {
    top: -104.5%; // adjust dynamic percent based on number of cards and width of each card
  }
}
```